# Caching web API proxy?

Tags: api, caching, proxy

I was wondering if anyone knows of a caching proxy specifically for dealing with API responses?

Ideally, I'd be able to declare what caching policy to use for different API semantics, e.g. cache album art for 1 day, cache favorite tweets for 5 minutes, cache map tiles forever, except invalidate when this other API is called.

I know about using Apache, Squid, etc for caching in general -- I'm just hoping for something with nicer usage semantics by restricting the design goal to dealing with APIs rather than the web in general.

Comment: caddy (https://caddyserver.com/) is another good one